# Should you use singular and plural of the same base variable name?

Tags: python, variables, naming

Is it smart to use the plural of a variable name e.g. to name a list of the same type like so:

```
language = 'English'
languges = ['English', 'German', 'French']
```

or should you rater use the type of the variable like so:

```
language = 'English'
languge_list = ['English', 'German', 'French']
```

Especially in large projects I tend to use the second example.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a team follow the team's naming conventions, if you're working on your own its personal preference.